# How to internally call another restapi endpoint in quarkus controller class?

Tags: java, rest, quarkus

I need to call another rest api endpoint inside the controller class to provide filtered user list as a result. I can't find a way to call one rest api from another rest api.[Controller class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzMWz.png)

This is my controller class method code:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/filter")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response filterByName(@QueryParam("page") int page, @QueryParam("first_name") String first_name,
            @QueryParam("last_name") String last_name) {
        try{
            String uri = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page="+page;
            //Flux<User1> users = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, User1.class);
            Mono<List<User1>> result = users.filter(user-> user.getFirst_name().equals(first_name) && user.getLast_name().equals(last_name)).collectList();
            return Response.ok(result).build();
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(204).build();
        }
    }
```

My issue got resolved, I used microprofile rest client to create a proxy and called the endpoint from there. Thanks!

Comment: please provide code as text in your question (you can easily format it with the "code fence"). 
Can you describe your problem a bit better? You have two controllers in your program and want to call a method in one of them from a method in the other one? (Please add the details to your question.)

Comment: Quarkus has its own module for rest client calls (https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client)

Comment: Why do you want to call the other controller through a REST call instead of just invoking the actual method (or a method that implements the actual logic you need)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The issue is that I am not able to find a way through which i can call another rest endpoint (https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1), from my controller class which is already consuming one rest api which i created. Actually i want to get a list of users from the above provided rest endpoint and compare it with inputs which i am consuming from my own created api.

Comment: Like in spring boot we can use rest template for the purpose, but i have to do the same in Quarkus. This is my controller class function code:

Comment: Please take a look of the update @cyberbrain

Comment: Still it is not completely clear to me: is the "other" rest endpoint also part of one of your controllers? (Not reqres.in for sure, since that is a testing util, but the real thing.)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the HttpClient class in java.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).